# Python Multiprocessing - execution time increased, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm doing a simple multiprocessing test and something seems off. Im running this on i5-6200U 2.3 Ghz with Turbo Boost.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time

def multiply(a,b,que): #add a argument to function for assigning a queue
    que.put(a*b) #we're putting return value into queue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue1 = Queue() #create a queue object
    jobs = []
    start_time = time.time()
#####PARALLEL####################################
    for i in range(0,400):
        p = p = Process(target= multiply, args= (5,i,queue1))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

    for j in jobs:
        j.join()

    print("PARALLEL %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
#####SERIAL################################
    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(0,400):
        multiply(5,i,queue1)
    print("SERIAL %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Output:

```
PARALLEL 22.12951421737671 seconds ---
SERIAL 0.004009723663330078 seconds ---
```

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Creating a process is far more expensive than multiplying two little integers; and creating far more processes than you have CPUs makes it  worse (all the processes fight with each other for limited CPU cycles).  To see any speedup, the "useful work" done in each worker process needs to be non-trivial (take more time than the overheads of process creation+destruction and IPC (interprocess communication)).

Comment: why create 400 processes and store multiply values into queue?

Comment: How am i properly supposed to do this then? Can you point me to the right resource? Should i be using pool or something? I'm really confused. I need to store the values into queue because I need to get the results of the process, and through googling, queue seemed to be the way to do it

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you did.  It's simply impossible to get a speedup when the work you're doing per process is so trivial that it's _far_ more expensive to create a process to begin with.  You can try using a `Pool` instead, with "just a few" processes (say, no more than the # of CPUs you have).  That will greatly cut the time wasted creating processes.  But it's still the case that IPC will remain more expensive than multiplying two small integers - you won't get any speedup.  What you need is a more expensive _problem_ to solve ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a brief example of (silly) code that gets a nice speedup.  As already covered in comments, it doesn't create an absurd number of processes, and the work done per remote function invocation is high compared to interprocess communication overheads.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def factor(n):
    for i in range(n):
        pass
    return n

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ns = range(100000, 110000)

    s = time.time()
    p = mp.Pool(4)
    got = p.map(factor, ns)
    print(time.time() - s)
    assert got == list(ns)

    s = time.time()
    got = [factor(n) for n in ns]
    print(time.time() - s)
    assert got == list(ns)
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot. However, how would I pass a 2D array (like an image) instead of n? That's one part I'm pretty confused about. And to get value back, would I still have to use a queue?

Comment: Stare at the code and you'll see it _does_ return results from `factor()`.  I don't know what "a 2D array (like an image)" means, exactly.  "2D array" and "image" are not builtin Python types.  Details matter.  In short, anything that can be pickled can be passed and/or returned

Comment: Thanks Tim, this helps me out a lot :)